# How can I prevent Xcode from installing iOS documentation?

Tags: xcode4

I have Xcode set to "Check for and install updates automatically" in the Downloads section of the preferences. If I remove the iOS 5.1 Library, it gets reinstalled automatically. Installing something new is not an "update". How can I prevent this?

Comment: Uncheck the box on the Documentation tab. "Check for and install updates automatically" are independent from "Components" and "Documentation".

Comment: I know that will do it, but I'd like to get updates for the things I *do* have installed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find it easier to tell Xcode not to search the iOS documentation than to get it to never install the iOS documentation. In the search field is a magnifying glass icon button. Click the button and choose Show Find Options.

When you show the find options you should see a Find in menu. Click the menu and you should see a check next to the iOS documentation. Choose the iOS documentation and the check should go away, and Xcode won't search the iOS documentation.

Comment: Yes, I know about that and I've done that. But in the Quick Help Inspector (and possibly some other context-sensitive areas), iOS is still the default.